# error NETSDK1064: Package DnsClient, 1.2.0 was not found

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I have an Asp.Net core docker image. The last time I tried building it was 2 months ago. Now, I'm getting an error while trying to build it.

Any ideas? Did something break the Microsoft docker image? This is also breaking when trying to publish and run on an Elasticbeanstalk instance.

Complete Error Log:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error NETSDK1064: Package DnsClient, version 1.2.0 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions. [/app/BacktraderDataApi.csproj]
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish -c Release -o out' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApp.dll"]
```

Answer (score 18):

When solutions like using `--no-cache` are not restoring at all work, it usually indicates that artifact from the host machine are getting copied into the build container.  This can cause problems when the host machine and build container have different RIDs.  This can commonly occur on Windows machines when running linux containers.  The .NET Core Docker Samples suggest using a [.dockerignore file](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/dotnetapp/.dockerignore) to avoid coping the bin and obj directories with your Dockerfiles.

Comment: This is a most accurate answer. 
And as mentioned in answer below, just make sure the `.dockerignore` file correctly ignores the bin and obj directories.

Answer (score 4):

For me it helped adding a `--no-cache flag`

```
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out --no-cache
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information posted at https://github.com/microsoft/containerregistry/issues/20 for this same issue as well as the information here I tried the following:

1. `dotnet new web`
2. Edit the csproj and added the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.10.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

3. Created the following Dockerfile

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and publish app and libraries
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore


# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

4. Created the following .dockerignore

```
# directories
**/bin/
**/obj/
**/out/

# files
Dockerfile*
**/*.trx
**/*.md
**/*.ps1
**/*.cmd
**/*.sh
```

5. `docker build --pull -t test .`

The Dockerfile built without issue.  Can you try these steps and report back the results?

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem

```
error MSB4018: NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder '/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder'.
```

I added `RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder`.

Then it got a lot farther but failed with a library resolution for something that I believe is just distributed with the SDK.

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers, version 3.1.1 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions.
```

I think the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1` 4/09/2010 Docker image with tags 3.1.201-buster, 3.1-buster, 3.1.201, 3.1, latest is broken.

I changed to the image based on Ubuntu bionic and it just worked again.

```
USE mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-bionic
```

Comment: If comment out 'RUN dotnet restore' the image will build

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, after i read this link https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3059

I just appended the `/restore` to build command and it worked.

just like this

```
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o /app --no-cache /restore
```

and now it is working just fine.

Comment: `--no-restore` and `/restore` at the same time?