# Build a image with dotnet core 6 using dockerfile get an error NETSDK1064

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, nuget-package

I'm tring to build a image with .net core 6, but when command ran to this line :

```
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore
```

I got a error:

> ```
> #14 0.629 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.101/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5):
> ```
>
> error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers,
> version 6.0.1 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet
> restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed,
> which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions.
> [/source/Dating_WebAPI.csproj]

so I checked my nuget manager, I dont download this package before.
but even I download it, the error still occur.
Did I miss something?

following Dockerfile:

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

step of dockerfile:

```
[+] Building 12.2s (14/15)                                                                                                                     
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 768B                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:latest                                                                   0.3s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:latest                                                                      0.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                         0.5s
 => => transferring context: 17.79MB                                                                                                      0.5s
 => [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk@sha256:a7af03bdead8976d4e3715452fc985164db56840691941996202cea411953452                 0.0s
 => [stage-1 1/3] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet@sha256:7696d5b456eede87434c232b9070f40659ff0c4b71ca622cf197815ccaee661d            0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /source                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [build 3/7] COPY *.csproj .                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [build 4/7] RUN dotnet clean                                                                                                          0.5s
 => [build 5/7] RUN dotnet restore                                                                                                       10.1s
 => [build 6/7] COPY . .                                                                                                                  0.1s 
 => ERROR [build 7/7] RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore
```

Comment: Try removing `--no-restore` on the publish command

Comment: check for latest version of EntityFrameworkCore for .net 6.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `--no-restore` from the `dotnet publish` should do the trick.

From the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish:

> You don't have to run dotnet restore because it's run implicitly by all commands that require a restore to occur, such as dotnet new, dotnet build, dotnet run, dotnet test, dotnet publish, and dotnet pack. To disable implicit restore, use the --no-restore option

Comment: Although that may work, you loose the advantage of caching layers in the docker build. The correct solution that will likely work is adding a .dockerignore file.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61510296/292410

Comment: Actually, remove the --no-restore flag solves the issue, but however I cannot explain why. I'd be interested because as @DavidDeSloovere suggests you lose a cache layer and my base image already restores packages. Moreover, on the remote DevOps agent it's working as a charm - I have problem this problem since a couple of hours on my machine only

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added `--no-cache /restore` to the publish stage.
Like so:
`RUN dotnet publish --no-restore --configuration Release --output /app/publish --no-cache /restore`